# I wanna rander a browser on the AR rendering object. Can three.js makes it?

Tags: three.js

There is a AR object and I want to Put a browser on it , so users can See that browser on the AR object. Can three.js makes it?

Comment: Unfortunately, as written, this question is off-topic as "too broad" and "unclear." Essentially it's currently a yes/no question, and you haven't shown any code or other context around what you've done so far, issues you've run into, etc. Please edit your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized it as using that Three.js exmaple called "Youtube"